# How to use TkInter fill or expand functions with self?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I have a very simple program with TkInter in Python.

How to I use the "fill" or "expand" options with the following code?

```
from Tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def sayhello(self):
        print "Hello!"

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.var = Button(self, text="Hello", command = self.sayhello)
        self.var.pack(side=LEFT)

        self.QUIT = Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red", command = self.quit)
        self.QUIT.pack(side=LEFT)

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Note: I have to use the self.var.pack() format so it can do a "command" when it's pressed...unless anyone has a better way?

Comment: what effect do you want to achieve? Do you want the button to fill the entire window? Which button? What about the frame, should it fill the window? Also, what do you mean by "use the self.var.pack() format"? That's not a format, that's simply how you use it, and it has nothing at all to do with using the command option the way your code is using it.

Comment: How do you get the Hello button to fill the Y axis of the window?

Answer (score 3):

To make an object fill it's container in the y axis, you would use the parameter `fill="y"` (or `fill=Y` if you import Y from Tkinter).

Note that this only controls how the widget fills its container. In your code, this makes the button fill the inner frame, but because your inner frame doesn't fill the main window in the y axis, you might not get the visual effect you expect.

Also, specifically in the case of buttons on the Macintosh, the button won't grow to fill the space. On OSX, buttons are native widgets which can't grow in height.

Comment: When experimenting with layouts, it helps a lot to give each widget its own (preferably garish) background color. Like that you can quickly see where space is *actually* going…

Comment: I realize this is quite an old post, but Bryan, I have been trying for hours to figure out why my buttons won't fill vertically on my Mac, and here I find the answer! I have posted my problem as it's own question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29935918/why-wont-my-button-widget-expand-vertically), but no one has been able to answer it. I would like to ask you, is there a quick and dirty way to get around this and allow the buttons to fill vertically on OS X? Or am I stuck with them being a fixed height?

Comment: @wgrenard: buttons on a mac will will be a fixed height and will not expand.