# Why won't my Button widget expand vertically

Tags: python, tkinter

I am familiarizing myself with Tkinter, and I am attempting to write a very simple program, which displays a button in a window, using the pack geometry manager.

I was experimenting with various configuration options for `pack()`, such as `expand`, `fill`, and `side`, and I've run into a peculiar problem. I have written the following code:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
widget = Button(root, text='text')
widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that the button expands to fill the window in the horizontal direction, but not the vertical direction. This is the same result that I get if instead of specifying `fill=BOTH` I use `fill=X`. In addition, if I specify instead `fill=Y` the button does not expand in either direction. Something seems to be going wrong with the fill in the vertical direction, and I cannot figure out what it might be.

I attempted to Google this problem and surprisingly found no mention of this happening to anyone else. I am using a Mac with OS X Yosemite and running python 2.7.5. I also attempted to compile with python 3.4.1 and saw no change.

**Edit:**

Based off of the answer and comments below, it is clear that there is nothing wrong with my code, because it seems to work on other machines. If not an error in the code, does anyone know what could possibly be causing the button to not stretch vertically when I run the above code?

Comment: When I test it works
http://i.imgur.com/cRozUhM.png

Comment: Just to be sure I just copied directly from the code I included above and ran it as is. It is expanding only horizontally. Could this be something having to do with my OS and the version of python I'm using having a bug or something?

Comment: I have python 2.7.9, 64bits, I'm on Win7 Enterprise 64 bits, but I doubt the OS can affect the result

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a feature of native buttons on OSX. Buttons on OSX will be a fixed height and will not expand vertically. There is nothing you can do, short of using a different widget such as a label.

Comment: Apologies on the late acceptance. Somehow I missed the fact that this answer was here until I happened to browse this question again today.

Comment: It is also possible to simply set a fixed height, like `Button(root, height=900, text='text')`.

Comment: @Delgan: like I said in the answer, that won't work on OSX.

Comment: I am having the same problem, however mine doesn't work horizontally either. Is this specific to mac high sierra python 3.6? @BryanOakley

Comment: That is too bad.  It seems on today's TKinter (MacOS Ventura) it just internally turns the button into a Label if it has to expand (it looses is nice rounded corners)

Answer (score 0):

try running this code to see the behavior of `fill` and `expand`

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
widget = Button(root, text='text1')
widget.pack(fill=X, expand=1)
widget = Button(root, text='text2')
widget.pack(fill=Y, expand=1)
widget = Button(root, text='text3')
widget.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Argument `fill` does fill in vertical direction as well

Comment: Here's a link to exactly what I am seeing when I run that code. http://imgur.com/gallery/WTq3jt3/new . . . I understand what it is supposed to look like, based off of the code. It's quite simple, but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working on my machine.

Comment: It definitely has nothing to do with Python version.

Answer (score 0):

I am also beginner, defining geometry for fill was missing in your code as given below:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x400")
widget = Button(root, text='text')
widget.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don’t think this works on OSX. See the accepted answer.

Comment: Can't comment on OSX. It was not working on windows OS but modifying this way was working for me.